# AngularJS - Cannot access ng-click in component when $compile is used

Tags: angularjs

I have a normal JS file that contains some utility functions. One of these utility functions are to return the AngularJS component `<tooltip>`. I know that this is not very good coding practice, but this is what I have to work with. I have one problem:

`onClickDescription()` does not trigger when I click on the `<p>`. It however gets triggered by `$onInit()`.

#### utility.js

```
function getTooltipHtml($compile, $scope) {
    const scope = $scope.$new();
    scope.description = getDescription();
    const html = '<tooltip description="{description}"></tooltip>';
    const element = $compile(angular.element(html))(scope);
    scope.$apply();
    return element.html();
}
```

#### tooltip.js

```
class Tooltip {
    $onInit() {
        this.onClickDescription();
    }

    onClickDescription() {
        console.log('onClickDescription()');
    }
}
export default {
    bindings: {
        description: '<'
    }
}
```

#### tooltip.html

```
<div class="tooltip">
    <p ng-click="$ctrl.onClickDescription()">{{ $ctrl.description }}</p>
</tooltip>
```

Comment: Does alert fire when you do ng-click="alert()"?

Comment: element.html() return String -- you can append it somewhere, but all bidings are lost forever.

Comment: @MokkyMiah Alert fire does not fire

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Is there a way to prevent the bindings from being lost? Or a work around?

Comment: @Jon return element and work with it